# Two-way angular binding for selected polymer paper-tab

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I'm trying to use the Polymer paper-tabs component in an Angular app. I have the markup like:

```
<paper-tabs noink selected="0">
   <paper-tab class="tab1" data-ng-click="currentTab='tab1'">Tab1</paper-tab>
   <paper-tab class="tab2" data-ng-click="currentTab='tab2'">Tab2</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

I want to be able to bind the selected `paper-tab` to an angular scope field, such that if I update the scope field, the markup re-renders to select the new tab that is somehow associated with the scope field's new value.

Is this possible? It seems that the only way to configure which tab is selected is via the `selected` attribte on `paper-tabs`. But if you programmatically update this value during the life of the page (either via jQuery or via an angular binding), then it doesn't cause the tabs to re-render with the new tab selected.

Comment: Are you using the polymer controls build specifically for AngularJS? https://material.angularjs.org/

Comment: No, it appears that we should be though... I'll check them out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the standard Polymer paper elements. As far as I know these webcomponents don't play that nicely with AngularJS and hence the [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) project was created

To do what you need the Angular Material should look like, from the [example](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.tabs):

```
<md-tabs selected="selectedIndex">
  <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs | orderBy:predicate:reversed" on-select="onTabSelected(tab)" on-deselect="announceDeselected(tab)" disabled="tab.disabled">
      <md-tab-label>
          {{tab.title}}
      </md-tab-label>
      {{tab.content}}
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The official docs on https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.tabs say <md-tabs md-selected = "selectedIndex"> </md-tabs> . I remained stuck on this till I saw the correct usage here was not md-selected but just selected!

Answer (score 1):

If You looking **solution** for "**standard Polymer paper elements**".

### Try [ng-polymer-elements](https://gabiaxel.github.io/ng-polymer-elements/)

AngularJS two-way binding for Web Components, whit support for Polymer Core and Paper elements

Just tested for me, and works great, in your case use:

```
<paper-tabs noink ng-model="currentTab">
```

link: https://gabiaxel.github.io/ng-polymer-elements/